# PMC Error: The term 'get-mgrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm new to the asp.net core and I'm developing an MVC App. I encountered an error trying to view entity framework migrations.

PMC command:

```
PM> get-migrations
```

Respond:

```
get-mgrations : The term 'get-mgrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-mgrations
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-mgrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I cant figure out what is wrong. My guess is that perhaps my dotnet framework is corrupted or something

I tried:

- reinstalling the VS2019
- deleting entityframeworkcore sdk folders and running `dotnet restore` command
- previously I fixed same error for the `nuget` command by identifying that nuget.exe was missing, downloading it and seting PATH to it (I hope You know what I mean)
- reinstalling the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App packege

Nothing helped

AdMarket.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-AdMarket-C5C71703-513A-471A-959E-3C883B2380D5</UserSecretsId>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.17" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\Identity\Services\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And the thing is that this same error occurs on other projects as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get-migrations` is not available as command in the Package Manager Console, see [Entity Framework Core tools reference - Package Manager Console in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell) for a list of available commands.

You could use the [CLI tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet), which provide the [dotnet ef migrations list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-list) command, or inspect the generated files in the [Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#create-a-migration) directory manually.